# Linq to count from inner lists

Tags: c#, linq, list

Let's suppose I have the following situation:

```
public class ABC
{

     public List<A> listA { get; set; }
     public List<B> listB { get; set; }
}

public class Test
{
    public void LetsCount(List<ABC> listABC)
    {
        //int total = it's the total of all listA plus the total of all listB inside listABC... is it possible via linq? 
    }
}
```

Is it possible to get this count via linq?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use simple [`Enumerable.Sum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535184%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (assume both listA and listB are not null, otherwise you need to add null-check):

```
int total = listABC.Sum(abc => abc.listA.Count + abc.listB.Count);
```

Comment: Man, how could I have forgotten about "Sum"... :-) Thanks!